# Text file of 256 bytes with 256 unique characters

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, compression, notepad++, ascii

I'm doing a data compression project and for this I need to have what the title implies.

I already have the first 128 unique characters (7 bit ASCII), see image below:

[image]

Sorry for small representation, you're just gonna have to click it to enlarge it '^-^

What you see in the image are the first 32 control characters (there's enters and whitespace characters in there so that's why it is 3 lines instead of one, but every newline is an unique character) followed by another 96 normal characters for up to a total of 128 unique characters containing what windows reports to be:

[image]

This is for 7 bits, all nice and dandy, but i need it for 8 bits. so 256 unique characters... Is there a way to get a text file which is 256 bytes in size which contains 256 unique characters? Much obliged!

**EDIT:** When asking this question I was confused about encoding and what it meant. So basically, a byte is just 8 times a 1 or 0. What that byte means is up to the encoding to tell. What I needed was a binary file of all combinations of 8 bits. Which CAN be interpreted as text, but it is not necessarily text. It can also be interpreted as something else, like numbers or colors.

Comment: Fill it up with all bytes from `0x00` to `0xFF`. Interpret the result in any single-byte character encoding like ISO-8859, and the content will show up as "characters".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this in Python:

```
b = bytearray(range(256))
f = open('test.txt','wb')
f.write(b)
f.close()
```

The resulting file has exactly 256 bytes, although it is more accurate to think of it as a binary file rather than a text file.

Comment: Yes, without specifying an encoding, it can't be interpreted as text. There is no text but encoded text. It's a binary file.

Comment: Genius, why didn't i think of this :D

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void all256() throws IOException {
    File f=new File("C:/.../test.txt");
    FileOutputStream rufos=new FileOutputStream(f);
    //(-128)->(0)->(127)
    int index=0;
    byte[] all_bytes=new byte[256];
    for (int i = -128; i < 0; i++,index++)all_bytes[index]=(byte)i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++,index++)all_bytes[index]=(byte)i;
    rufos.write(all_bytes);
    rufos.close();
    }
```